# Not closing HTML5 tags to avoid whitespace between inline elements - is this correct?

Tags: html

I've been curious about this for some time now.

According to this article I read, [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) it is okay to skip the end tags for the `li` to prevent the whitespace that is created between each element due to the style `inline` or `inline-block`.

I am a very anal person when it comes to the writing of my html and try my best to keep a clean structure. Recently I have been commenting the whitespace out between the elements which has brought concern to myself due to load time and a sloppy feel.

> "Skip the closing tag HTML5 doesn't care anyway."

```
<ul>
  <li>one
  <li>two
  <li>three
</ul>
```

Compared to the classic way,

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Is this valid `html` and is there the possibility that this may cause complications later down the road?

Comment: According to the spec, the 1st method is fine.  `An li element’s end tag may be omitted if the li element is immediately followed by another li element or if there is no more content in the parent element.`  http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/li.html

Comment: The question does not explain what you expect to achieve by the omission of end tags. A parenthetic remark in the question title and a link to a live site do not constitute a proper question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela In my title I am stating what it is for, whitespace from inline. This was a suggested answer to remove the whitespace between inline elements and then I wanted to know if this is a valid option. Any suggestions on how I can improve my answer?

Comment: The parenthetic remark “for whitespace from inline” is obscure to put it mildly. A question should be comprehensible on its own, without looking at the title or following any links. By accepting an answer that simply states (correctly) what the HTML rules are, you leave it completely open what the *problem* was.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I see what you are saying. There are many ways of dealing with the witespace and I just was unsure if this is even valid. Thank you for helping me understand where you are coming from. I can't remove the question so I'm going to try and improve it.

Comment: Hmmm, on what basis was this question nominated for reopening? The close reason "unclear what you're asking" raises my eyebrows, because I think it's pretty clear what's being asked, but it should be closed as "primarily opinion-based", since it's asking for subjective opinions on which of two equally valid ways of writing code are better style.

Comment: @AdiInbar You may be right; I voted to reopen on the basis that the reason for closing seemed absurd, but perhaps it should be closed for the reason you've given.

Comment: @MarkAmery Heh...I don't think there's a mechanism for voting the change the close reason. Maybe if this question ends up getting reopened and reclosed, that would make the case that there should be.

Comment: I was not planning for it to be opinion based but rather if it was valid. I was unsure if this would cause complications or problems by using that technique. Any suggestion on how I can better my question?

Comment: @JoshPowell Yeah. Ask exactly that - something like "Is this valid HTML, and will using it cause any problems or complications in modern browsers? Are there any other good reasons to avoid this technique?" You could also drop the references to it being 'clean looking' but 'feeling weird', which could be interpreted as a prompt for discussion about coding aesthetics without regard for practicality. You also say at the end that this doesn't seem like "an okay option", but don't explain why; perhaps either scrapping that sentence or explaining your reasoning could add some clarity.

Comment: @MarkAmery I have updated my answer to be more clear and not opinionated.

Comment: Okay, that makes the question more appropriate for SO's format. I just cast a reopen vote, you need one more.

Comment: @AdiInbar Thank you for casting your vote, hopefully it will be reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End tags were optional on list items since at least the first standardised version of HTML (HTML 2) was released in 1995. (Edit: Also optional in [the first public document that specified HTML](http://www.w3.org/History/19921103-hypertext/hypertext/WWW/MarkUp/Tags.html), published in 1992).

It was only XHTML that made end tags mandatory, and practically nobody ever used the `application/xhtml+xml` content-type that would make that matter, even when XHTML was the flavour of the week.

Comment: It just feels very weird to me. Currently I have been commenting out the white space but I also hate that option. I figured if this was valid I would give it a try.

Comment: I feel sorry for everyone who learned HTML while being subjected to XML-ra-ra.

Comment: maybe it's because I have feelings for (La)TeX… anyway I think it's almost wrong to need to close certain tags

Answer (score 1):

The classic way was the XHTML way. XHTML is actually XML, which demands you close your tags or else your pages wouldn't validate.

If you write your pages to be consistent with the HTML5 specification, it is ok to not close those tags (but I do it anyway!)

Just make sure your pages validate: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Hmm very interesting, I always make sure my pages validate. This just seemed like a very odd option to fight the white space and to me just feels wrong lol.

Comment: the classical way was `html` `xhtml 1.0` was the try to push `html 4.01` into the direction of `xml`. Already in `html 4.1` I it was allowed to not close the tags ( [Introduction to lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html) ). The try to make `html` to `xml`  was a complete failure.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 is very tolerant of open tags.  However I would personally recommend always closing the tags.  Its just good practice.

This is especially the case if you are developing web projects that mix other languages and markup, like XML, PHP, Javascript, etc.  It will help greatly when it comes to debugging.